# OpenWire JMS client stops consuming messages after migrating to ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

When Artemis Broker 2.28.0 is used in lieu of ActiveMQ "Classic" one of our applications is behaving weirdly. Shortly after the clean start it stops consuming (then also producing) messages. Restarting the application won't help much. It will consume few messages then stall again. Artemis console is showing that the consumers are connected, however no consumption is happening. Both application and broker logs show no errors nor warnings so a silent stale mate. Same application works fine when ActiveMQ "Classic" broker is used.

The application is a Spring Web Application (not Spring Boot) that uses Spring Integration to orchestrate asynchronous tasks. It uses the following dependencies:

- <org.springframework.version>5.3.20</org.springframework.version>
- <org.springframework.integration.version>5.4.13</org.springframework.integration.version>
- <org.apache.activemq.version>5.15.9</org.apache.activemq.version>

Here are the application's `ConnectionFactory` configurations:

```xml
<!-- JMS ConnectionFactory -->
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="${jmsBrokerUrl}" />
            <!-- <property name="trustAllPackages" value="true"/> -->
            <property name="trustedPackages">
                <list>
                    <value>java.lang</value>
                    <value>java.util</value>
                    <value>java.sql</value>
                    <value>our.custom.domain</value>
                    <value>org.hibernate</value>
                    <value>org.springframework</value>
                    <value>java.io</value>
                    <value>java.net</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="maxConnections" value="5" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="0" />
</bean>
```

**Things tried while troubleshooting:**

- **Checked Logs**: Both application and broker logs show no errors nor warnings.
- **Reducing prefetch policy**: I tried setting `jms.prefetchPolicy.all=1` since producer generates large number of messages. It had no effect.
- **Examined differences in broker configurations**: The only thing that caught my eye was this configuration on ActiveMQ "Classic" that I could not find in Artemis' [broker.xml](https://pastebin.com/raw/DMzpU7FR):

  ```xml
  <!-- publicrelay needs this -->
  <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true">
      <pendingQueuePolicy>
          <vmQueueCursor/>
      </pendingQueuePolicy>
  </policyEntry>
  ```
- **Examined Memory usage**: The issue seems to be unrelated to memory. I noticed the issue both when the broker is running high and low on memory. Increasing heap size didn't help. I realized that the issue is happening before brokers starts paging so I have not played much with paging-related configurations. ActiveMQ "Classic" rarely persisted messages while supporting this application so it shouldn't run out of memory during the normal processing.
- **`artemis queue stat`** output when consumption stalls:

  ```
  |NAME                     |ADDRESS                  |CONSUMER_COUNT|MESSAGE_COUNT|MESSAGES_ADDED|DELIVERING_COUNT|MESSAGES_ACKED|SCHEDULED_COUNT|ROUTING_TYPE|
  |DLQ                      |DLQ                      |0             |0            |0             |0               |0             |0              |ANYCAST     |
  |ExpiryQueue              |ExpiryQueue              |0             |0            |0             |0               |0             |0              |ANYCAST     |
  |activemq.management.93...|activemq.management.93...|1             |0            |0             |0               |0             |0              |MULTICAST   |
  |dedupe.aggregate.queue   |dedupe.aggregate.queue   |5             |0            |54            |0               |54            |0              |ANYCAST     |
  |dedupe.article.queue     |dedupe.article.queue     |10            |0            |5308          |0               |5308          |0              |ANYCAST     |
  |dedupe.final.response....|dedupe.final.response....|1             |0            |0             |0               |0             |0              |ANYCAST     |
  |dedupe.indexer.queue     |dedupe.indexer.queue     |5             |0            |5308          |0               |5308          |0              |ANYCAST     |
  |dedupe.jaccards.queue    |dedupe.jaccards.queue    |5             |366          |5308          |366             |4942          |0              |ANYCAST     |
  |dedupe.mlt.queue         |dedupe.mlt.queue         |10            |0            |5308          |0               |5308          |0              |ANYCAST     |
  |dedupe.rollinghash.queue |dedupe.rollinghash.queue |5             |0            |4942          |0               |4942          |0              |ANYCAST     |
  |dedupe.topic.stream      |dedupe.topic.stream      |5             |301          |1732          |301             |1431          |0              |ANYCAST     |
  ```
- **[Broker thread dump](https://pastebin.com/raw/LqhQqJnF) when consumption stalls**
- **[Application thread dump](https://pastebin.com/raw/zEvZADin) when consumption stalls**: It shows no blocked threads or anything that would show that threads are stopped in our application's code. The only thing worth noticing is that a producer thread seems to be stalled attempting to send a message.

Is there anything else I can do to troubleshoot this behavior?

Comment: The stack trace given shows a stall on producer create, it is waiting on an Openwire Response command from the broker.

Comment: Answered to above questions in the original post! Thanks @JustinBertram for jumping to help

Comment: Which address is the producer sending to and which queue is the consumer receiving from? Both queues `dedupe.jaccards.queue` and `dedupe.topic.stream` have messages and consumers.

Comment: Do you have a way to reproduce this that you could provide here via a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The thread dump from the broker indicates that it's basically not doing any work. However, in the application thread dump there are 8 ActiveMQ threads waiting to commit a transaction, 1 waiting to send a message, 7 unmarshalling data from a socket, and 39 waiting to receive a message (i.e. doing nothing). Something strange is definitely going on.

Comment: Could you perhaps try a more recent version of the OpenWire JMS client? Version 5.15.9 was released back in 2019. I'm grasping at straws here without a way to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The application performs a springIntegration asynchronous workflow as part of which it's moving messages from `dedupe.topic.stream -> dedupe.indexer.queue -> dedupe.article.queue -> dedupe.jaccards.queue ... etc` performing various transformations along the way. At the time I took the dumps it got stalled with messages in  `dedupe.jaccards.queue` and `dedupe.topic.stream` queues. (But it's been stalled in other queues as well). `dedupe.topic.stream` - initiates the workflow... it's the queue where stalled producer is trying to send messages.

Comment: I'm struggling with a reproducible usecase unfortunately, it's happening consistency in all higher environments but I cannot reproduce it locally for some weird reason. Will let you know if I manage to find such use case.

Comment: Hm... so if 7 threads are unmarshaling data from socket... could it be some sort of concurrency issue with unmarshaling? The payload that is moved from queue to queue is our custom domain object... are there any unmarshaling related configurations that we can play with? Or is there a way to set a timeout for how long a thread can spend unmarshalling an individual message to prove this theory?

Comment: Tried upgrading activemq_client to 5.17.4 (Feb 25, 2023), still no luck :-(

Comment: I'm not aware of any (un)marshalling related configuration options for the OpenWire JMS client, but I'm not an expert on that client either. The main thing we really need is a way to reproduce the problem. Aside from that you could try grabbing a handful of thread dumps from the client application when it stalled so that we can actually see what's happening _over time_ rather than just a snapshot. You could also activate TRACE logging for `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.OpenWireConnection` on the broker so we could see the OpenWire commands coming and going.

Comment: Any update here? Did you get this sorted?

Comment: Finding reproducible usecase would be a challenge since it involves our custom domain that I don't think our company would be willing to disclose :-( We decided to stay on a classic ActiveMQ for a time being, hoping that further versions of Artemis will address this. Thanks for you help Justin!